# ATOM how to enable selecting "$" symbol along with the variable name?

Tags: atom-editor

I am using ATOM as my IDE. Whenever I double click on a variable it selects only the variable name and leaves out `$`. For example, if I double click on variable `$var` it will only highlight `var` and `$` will not get highlighted. I am using the default nonWordCharacters in settings `/\()"':,.;<>~!@#$%^&*|+=[]{}?-…`. How can I enable highlighting the whole variable including the `$` sign?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's very simple. I believe currently you are trying to mess with "Non Word Characters" under `Settings > Editor > Non Word Characters`. Which is wrong. Leave that as it is (default). Changing that will have no effect. You need to change the "Non Word Characters" value under your preferred programming language's language preferences. Assuming that you are using PHP (since PHP is the language that uses `$` symbol to define a variable name), please follow the steps below:

1. Navigate to `Settings > Packages > Search for language-php`
2. Click on settings
3. Scroll down to find "Non Word Characters"
4. Remove `$` symbol from the list of the characters

That's it. Done! Now double clicking will select whole variable including the `$` symbol. If you are using any other language instead of PHP just make sure to search for `language-yourlanguagename` in the first step above.

Comment: Amazing... That worked! Thanks :)

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: wonderful, solved! `[+1]`